# Executing a Remote.Linq expression against data

Tags: serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using [Remote.Linq](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq/) to serialise / deserialise my **Expressions** as I want to create the ability to send dynamic *expressions* from a client application to our web services. Standard .NET expressions cannot be serialised so I'm using **Remote.Linq** instead.

However, I cannot see how to execute the **Expression**. Normally I would invoke the *Compile*() and *Invoke*() methods to execute the **Expression** against the data. But **Remote.Linq** expressions don't support such methods.

The following unit test may explain more clearly what I'm trying to achieve.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SerializeLinqExpressionsTests()
{
    var testdata = GetTestdata();

    Expression<Func<ModuleEntityAdmins, ModuleEntityAdmin>> expr1 = m => m.Modules.Find(q => q.Id == 1);
    var remoteExpression1 = expr1.ToRemoteLinqExpression();
    string strexpr1 = SerialiseExpression(remoteExpression1);

    try
    {
        var deserexpr1 = DeserialiseExpression<Remote.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression>(strexpr1.NormalizeJsonString());

        //what is the equivalent of doing this with a Remote.Linq Expression?
        var compiled1 = expr1.Compile();
        var result = compiled1.Invoke(testdata);

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Id == 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Assert.Fail("Error deserialising LINQ expression tree");
    }
}
```

How do you invoke a **Remote.Linq** expression?

Answer (score 1):

A remote linq expression may be converted back into a system linq expression and be compiled and executed as such.

However, this is not what you actually want when sending expressions to a server to query data. On server side you want to use the `Execute` extension methods to execute your expression against a data source. Make sure to add a using for namespace `Remote.Linq.Expressions`.

Here's the sample code from [Remote.Linq](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq) source repo:

```
using Remote.Linq.Expressions;

public interface IQueryService
{
    IEnumerable<DynamicObject> ExecuteQuery(Expression queryExpression);
}

public class QueryService : IQueryService, IDisposable
{
    // any linq provider e.g. entity framework, nhibernate, ...
    private IDataProvider _datastore = new ObjectRelationalMapper();

    // you need to be able to retrieve an IQueryable by type
    private Func<Type, IQueryable> _queryableProvider = type => _datastore.GetQueryableByType(type);

    public IEnumerable<DynamicObject> ExecuteQuery(Expression queryExpression)
    {
        // `Execute` is an extension method provided by Remote.Linq
        // it applies an expression to a data source and returns the result
        return queryExpression.Execute(queryableProvider: _queryableProvider);
    }

    public void Dispose() => _datastore.Dispose();
}
```

Also, there are additional nuget packages for expression execution with EF and EF Core, so you can simply provide a `DbContext` to the Execute method.

In addition you may want to check out the demos/samples found in the project's github repo.